# Ping to subnet on IPsec Host only works with -I parameter

Tags: routes, openvpn, ipsec

I have the following situation. Two hosts connect two subnets over the Internet using Strongswan IpSec

- Host 1 a router for subnet 10.13.0.0/24
- Host 2 is rented dedicated Ubuntu server with no subnet (ifconfig says submask is Mask:255.255.255.255)
- Host 2 also hosts another subnet using OpenVpn. That subnet is 192.168.23.0/24
- Host 2 has 192.168.23.1 as Ip on that subnet.

When do ping -I 192.168.23.1 10.23.23.23 I can reach the other server. when I do ping 10.23.23.23 it doesn't work. On all other clients in the 192.168.0./24 network, the ping does work.

Which routing entry do I have to add to make it work? Because now the host itself cannot reach clients on the other side.

Further info:
host2 has two interfaces: eth0 and tun0 (for openvpn)

ipconfig on host2 looks like this:

```
charonstart=yes
plutostart=yes
left=host2externalIp
leftsubnet=192.168.23.0/24
leftnexthop=host2router
right=remoteIp
rightsubnet=10.13.0.0/24
```

---

Found the answer here: http://www.freeswan.org/freeswan_trees/freeswan-1.99/doc/adv_config.html#multitunnel

It is possible, with some extra configuration. Unfortunately I don't control the configuration on the other side so it didn't work for me.

Comment: the good folks over at http://serverfault.com will probably be able to help you better :) SO is mostly for programming

Answer (score 1):

it does not ping, because when pinging from host2, ping is using your public IP address (from eth0) as source.

kernel rules for IPSec say, that only traffic from 192.168.23.0/24 => 10.13.0.0/24 is going through that tunnel.

you need to add NAT to make it work, something like:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -s 192.168.23.0/24 -d 10.13.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.23.1
```

Answer (score 0):

mighq nailed the problem, but went in the wrong direction for a solution (or maybe 3 years ago the correct direction was too difficult to reach).

Problem: You already configured your firewall to allow the outbound packets out to the default gateway, BUT you didn't include the endpoint that is that final interface in your list of networks.

Solution: Add the uplink IP (the address that the router uses to talk to the default gateway) to the list of left/right networks via a /32 or /128 masked network.

Answer (score 0):

dont forget to add route to remote net in your gate example ip r add <net/mask> dev  too.